# SSH Remote Host Identification Has Changed Error and Unable To Modify SSH Keys

Tags: macos, ssh, verification

I have a MacBook and by mistake I tried to setup password less `ssh` access for GitHub and definitely messed things up. I am new to MacOS and I have no idea how to solve the below.

When I try to establish a `ssh` connection, I get the following:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:DrvZ0osXO8YCnPwEaWyiGKf/SxQGcCZBoNcPrhEdKmI.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/rakeshravi/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/rakeshravi/.ssh/known_hosts:4
RSA host key for rivanna.hpc.virginia.edu has changed and you have requested strict checking.
lost connection
```

Based on my research in online forums, I attempted to execute the following command but unfortunately, it did not work.

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

I get the following as response.

> do_known_hosts: hostkeys_foreach failed: No such file or directory

Answer (score 6):

You can open with your favorite editor file `/Users/rakeshravi/.ssh/known_hosts` and delete line 4 and save the file. And next time you try to connect to the host you will be asked to add the new key to `known_hosts`

Comment: I tried doing this but there seems to be no folder directory called known_hosts. When I looked into the folder, only the following files were present.

`cat id_rsa.pub | pbcopy  cat id_rsa.pub | pbcopy.pub id_rsa`

Comment: @RakeshRavi this is file. Please check in directory `/Users/rakeshravi/.ssh`

Comment: I did and I found one two files inside it which are in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Add the option `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"`. This will suppress any checking.

```
ssh root@localhost -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may happen because another fingerprint is associated with your machine IP Address.

Try to remove Known Hosts list:

`rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

Other answers are fine, but here is what I did and worked fine.

Completely got rid of the following two files.

For me I am just playing with vms on azure, so its fine for me.

[image: know hosts file]